# Restricting cardinality of an element depending on its attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

How can I restrict the cardinality of the param element when it has no attributes?
I want it to have a max occurence of 1 (it behaves at app level as default param)
So this is valid

```
<xml>
    <param>value</param>
    <param id="1">value</param>
    <param id="2">value</param>
    <param id="3">value</param>
</xml>
```

but this is not

```
 <xml>
    <param>value</param>
    <param>value2</param>
    <param id="1">value</param>
    <param id="2">value</param>
    <param id="3">value</param>
</xml>
```

So far, I tried with

a definition of both a param xs:element with no attirbute specified and another with attribute specified, wrapped within a xs:choice. But it does not allow me to use two elements with the same name

Comment: Can you modify your XML source in any way? Adding an attribute, for example?

Comment: Well this is more a theoretical question, I could add "default" attribute. Perhaps it's a matter of bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are designing the schema, it would be best to have a `<param>` with a different name, since *it is* a different thing after all. In **XSD 1.0**, elements with the same names should contain represent the same types. If it had an `id` attribute with a fixed value, you could use an uniqueness constraint (which would also affect the other `param` elements) restricting any elements with the same `id`. That would also limit its occurrence to 0 or 1.

If you can't change the XML, an alternative is to use a parser with **XSD 1.1** support. In XSD 1.1 you can have [alternative types](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative) for the same elements. You can also use [assertions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions) to enforce rules using XPath, for example using a test like `count(param[not(@id)]) <= 1` in the context of the parent node:

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="param" maxOccurs="unbounded">...</xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:assert test="count(param[not(@id)]) le 1" />
</xs:complexType>
```